# Unable to install pyTenable using PIP via Windows

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install pyTenable using pip from Windows PowerShell. I am using Python 3.10
From the PowerShell

I performed pip command

```
pip install pyTenable
```

It showed an Error relating to SSL Error SSL CertVerificationError and could not find the module.

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pytenable/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pytenable/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pytenable/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pytenable/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pytenable/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pytenable/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pytenable/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyTenable (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyTenable
```

I tried to fix the SSL error and install pyTenable and it showed an error.

```
ERROR: HTTP error 403 while getting https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/48/e2f38f1dbb0ba2fc1bc76680f87a35c4395ab434398cec3451e7f72b2032/pyTenable-1.4.7-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=a70fea40a6186b3b8c415dadbcc146f9dcd060bb1d26bd270c01e02ce91f9f78 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pytenable/)
ERROR: Could not install requirement pyTenable from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/48/e2f38f1dbb0ba2fc1bc76680f87a35c4395ab434398cec3451e7f72b2032/pyTenable-1.4.7-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=a70fea40a6186b3b8c415dadbcc146f9dcd060bb1d26bd270c01e02ce91f9f78 because of HTTP error 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/48/e2f38f1dbb0ba2fc1bc76680f87a35c4395ab434398cec3451e7f72b2032/pyTenable-1.4.7-py3-none-any.whl?_sm_nck=1 for URL https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/48/e2f38f1dbb0ba2fc1bc76680f87a35c4395ab434398cec3451e7f72b2032/pyTenable-1.4.7-py3-none-any.whl#sha256=a70fea40a6186b3b8c415dadbcc146f9dcd060bb1d26bd270c01e02ce91f9f78 (from https://pypi.org/simple/pytenable/)
```

I tried to upgrade the pip

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Error showed

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\ieuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python310\lib\site-packages (22.1.2)
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)'))) - skipping
```

Please kindly help.

Thank you

Comment: Can you try to upgrade the pip by `pip install --upgrade pip` and then install the package.

Comment: @peerpressure I have tried performing your commands and it mention requirement already satisfied and SSL error SSL Cert Verification. I have attached the error above for your review.

Comment: are you using it on your personal computer or any computer given by your organization behind some kind of firewall or proxy?

Comment: one more thing you can is `pip install pyTenable config --global http.sslVerify false` .